# Set verify_certs=False yet elasticsearch.Elasticsearch throws SSL error for certificate verify failed

Tags: python, ssl, elasticsearch

self.host="KibanaProxy"

self.Port="443"

self.user="test"

self.password="test"

I need to suppress certificate validation. It works with curl when using option `-k` on command line. But while connecting using elasticsearch.Elasticsearch from Elasticsearch python module, it throws error.

`_es2 = Elasticsearch([self.host], port=self.port, scheme="https", http_auth=(self.user, self.password), use_ssl=True, verify_certs=False)`

`_es2.info()`

Error:

````
    raise SSLError('N/A', str(e), e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.SSLError: ConnectionError([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] 
certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)) caused by: SSLError([SSL: 
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590))```
````

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found it.
While reading this post https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/275, i got to know about connection_class. Looked for some standard or predefined method related to it so found https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/transports.html

Solution:

`from elasticsearch import RequestsHttpConnection`

.....

`_es2 = Elasticsearch([self.host], port=self.port, connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection, http_auth=(self.user, self.password), use_ssl=True, verify_certs=False)`

`print(es.ping())`

`$ ./sn.py`

True

Comment: Wow, thank you.  Additionally you *need* to manually install the `requests` module to make use of RequestsHttpConnection.  They're not bundled together.

Comment: thanks, @Sonali Srivastava, that solved my issue as well.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Sonali's answer, as of September 2022, the Python Elasticsearch client does not allow function parameter `use_ssl=True`

Adding only `verify_certs=False` parameter fixed my case:

```
Elasticsearch(hosts=[address], basic_auth=[user, password], verify_certs=False)
```

And `es.ping()` does not let you know what is the error, just returns `False`. In order to see the error details, you can use this single line of code

```
print(es.info())

TLS error caused by: TlsError(TLS error caused by: SSLError([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)))
```