# CURL works for an Elasticsearch instance but Python interfaces do not: what am I missing?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, ssl-certificate

The devops team at my company has set up an Elasticsearch/Kibana server for me. Everything works fine through the Kibana interface (including Dev Tools), however, I am having trouble accessing the server via Python. I think it's an SSL issue, but I'm sure if my diagnosis is correct or what exactly I have to do to fix it.

The following command returns a list of indexes as expected.

```
curl -u "username:password" -k https://server/_cat/indicies
```

The Elasticsearch Python client fails like so.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

basic_auth = ("username", "password")
host = "https://server"
elasticsearch_client = Elasticsearch({"host": host, "scheme": "https"}, basic_auth=basic_auth)
elasticsearch_client.indices.get("*")

...
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa6c8f96920>:
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known) caused by: 
NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa6c8f96920>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

In an attempt to work around SSL restrictions by following a solution to the ["Set verify_certs=False yet elasticsearch.Elasticsearch throws SSL error for certificate verify failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454126/set-verify-certs-false-yet-elasticsearch-elasticsearch-throws-ssl-error-for-cert) question I tried

```py
from elasticsearch import RequestsHttpConnection

elasticsearch_client = Elasticsearch(
    [host],
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
    http_auth=("username", "password"),
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=False,
)

elasticsearch_client.indices.get("*")
```

But that results in:

```
...
File /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/maintainer-text/lib/python3.10/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py:330, in Connection._raise_error(self, status_code, raw_data)
    327 except (ValueError, TypeError) as err:
    328     logger.warning("Undecodable raw error response from server: %s", err)
--> 330 raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(
    331     status_code, error_message, additional_info
    332 )

NotFoundError: NotFoundError(404, 'Not Found', 'Not Found')
```

(Can you set things up on the server side to disallow ignoring SSL certificates?)

Trying to move one level lower, if I use `requests` I get

```
import requests

requests.get("https://server/_cat/indicies", auth=("username", "password"))

...
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='es-api.dev.sparkgov.ai', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /_cat/indicies (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

It looks like my problem is that I don't have the proper SSL certificate. CURL knows how to get around this, by all my Python tools don't. Is this a correct diagnosis?

Do I [ask my dev ops team for a .pem file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61961725/connect-to-elasticsearch-with-python-using-ssl)? How do I get this to work?

Comment: What if you make your code look exactly like the example [in the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/config.html)? Remove the `use_ssl` parameter, and instead of a hostname pass an `https://` url as the first parameter. Does that result in the same behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to Elasticsearch with python using SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61961725/how-to-connect-to-elasticsearch-with-python-using-ssl)

Answer (score 0):

You `host` is wrong, it should just be like this since the `https` scheme is in another variable

```
host = "server"
```

It's not an SSL issue as with curl you specify `-k` which means [skip SSL verification](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-k)